PyQT5 - Live preview of markdown within the same text widget (without separate or second widget)
I ended up trying making a live preview text editor prototype in PyQT5 using a single widget. First I attempted to make the usual two widget implementation, for testing/comparing, using two separate panes:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QTextEdit
import markdown

class MarkdownEditor(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Markdown Editor with Live Preview")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.text_edit = QTextEdit()
        self.text_edit.textChanged.connect(self.update_preview)

        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.live_preview = QTextEdit()
        self.live_preview.setReadOnly(True)
        self.live_preview.setStyleSheet("background-color: #f0f0f0; border: none;")

        layout.addWidget(self.live_preview)

    def update_preview(self):
        markdown_text = self.text_edit.toPlainText()
        html_content = markdown.markdown(markdown_text, extensions=['extra'])
        self.live_preview.setHtml(html_content)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MarkdownEditor()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

but since that worked, I wanted to make another different version, this time where the live preview happens in the same text widget, without a secondary widget to display it (similar to Obsidian):
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QTextEdit
import markdown
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

class MarkdownLiveEditor(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Markdown Editor with Inline Live Preview")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.text_edit = QTextEdit()
        self.text_edit.textChanged.connect(self.update_preview)

        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)

        # Use a QTextEdit to edit and display HTML
        self.preview = QWebEngineView()

        # Setting initial display
        self.update_preview()

    def update_preview(self):
        # Block signals to prevent infinite recursion
        self.text_edit.blockSignals(True)

        markdown_text = self.text_edit.toPlainText()
        html_content = markdown.markdown(markdown_text, extensions=['extra'])

        # Update the HTML content of the editor without triggering textChanged
        self.text_edit.setHtml(html_content)

        # Re-enable signals after the update is complete
        self.text_edit.blockSignals(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MarkdownLiveEditor()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

This somewhat works, but as can be seen in the GIF it reverses the blinking cursor position (where I'm typing) and the text too.

I also had to use self.text_edit.blockSignals because the line self.text_edit.setHtml(html_content) caused infinite recursion. If it was just the text, I could reverse it, but it seems the cursor position is also affected. There is also no way to input any whitespace (newlines, space, etc).
Any way to fix this or make the correct implementation?

Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64841738/13629335 ?

I didn't no, but after looking through it and trying the code, it does not follow the "within the same text widget" since it work by switching through two different text widget. You basically have to switch manually too, etc @Thingamabobs

I sincerely doubt you could (or should) do any of that just by instantly replacing the content while typing, and for many reasons: first of all, you're only considering the case of typing at the end of the text, but if any markdown "token" is typed before the end, it would certainly alter the result in unexpected ways, not to mention the fact that all markdown syntax would be lost, making editing of fragments difficult and annoying. Also, as the documentation explains, using setHtml() completely clears the undo/redo history, so you'd eventually need to implement it on your own. The reason »

» of the cursor position change is that setHtml() completely resets the contents of the underlying QTextDocument and QTextCursor data, therefore it's almost like showing a new QTextEdit, which always has its position at the beginning. While you could eventually use QTextCursor to restore the previous position, it would also be unreliable, especially when using markdown symbols that would eventually be translated into formatting. Making a "live markdown" editor in Qt is not impossible, but also very complex: simply using the textChanged signal with setHtml() is unreliable and uneffective.

Yeah, you're right. I actually noticed that when trying to fix it myself. I did manage to find a way to store the last cursor position and restore it, and it does work. Now last problem is handling newlines/space, but it seems to e the hardest part. Also yes, I know it's not impossible given existing software do it (e.g.: Obsidian, etc). If you have a better or more reliable way than with the prototype in my question, I'm glad to have any suggestion :) @musicamante

Using setHtml() will still make restoring the cursor position unreliable: for instance, if you begin an highlighted fragment with *, then when you type it again to end the fragment, the position will have a wrong offset due to the removed characters; you may have not noticed that because you probably tested it at the end of the document (which would also give an illegal cursor position, in that case). Leading/trailing spaces and new lines are probably stripped away because that's how HTML works, and that's a further reason for which the setHtml() approach is not effective for this.

The only way to properly achieve all this is by going through the Qt Rich Text Processing API, using the QTextCursor interface for both editing and syntax/format checking, while carefully checking the context of each text block (to verify if any "fenced" control character requires changes in formatting) and also ensuring that each modification is possibly joining the previous edit block, in order to provide transparent undo/redo usage. As said, it's not impossible, but you cannot do any of that until you have profound knowledge of the rich text API of Qt.
